# Google Calendar API gives ParseError when subscribing to notifications

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api

When creating a notification channel for Google Calendar API, I'm getting some 400 Parse Error in certain cases (works most of the time):

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Here is my code:

```php
$channel             = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($googleCalendar->getClient());
        $channel->setId($id);
        $channel->setType('web_hook');
        $channel->setAddress($address);
        $channel->setToken($token);

        return $googleCalendar->getService()->events->watch($calendarId, $channel);
```

I have certain users generating this error, certain work properly. `$calendarId` is `primary` for me and most of my users, but I'm wondering if some users connect with another gmail account, or a workspace account, what would happen with the `primary` calendar. Would that be an issue here ?
Anyone has encountered such error yet ?
Thanks

Comment: Adding more details here. I see in the console that requests working 48h ago don't work anymore. Anyone knows if anything has changed on google's side ? I'm in touch with their support and will update the thread as we move on/if

Comment: I downgraded "google/apiclient-services" to "v0.288.0" and it works perfectly again. Using the last version v0.289.1 reproduces the problem in 100% of the cases.

Comment: had the same error. updated to v0.290.0 seems to have fixed it